# Java app runs perfectly with external .ttf loaded, but its JAR export throws a font-related null pointer

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, jar

Making a Java application on OSX 10.12.5 in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a running Java 9. My project is structured with an outer project file directly containing only three children: a package with all of my java and class files, a folder containing images and a folder containing fonts (the latter two named ICONS and FONTS, respectively).

I've downloaded a custom font for the application, which is applied throughout the project as follows:

```
label.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:FONTS/domesticmanners.ttf", 40));
```

Everything works as it should when running the app in Eclipse and from the command line, and when I export the project to a jar from the command line, via...

```
jar cvfm /Users/user/Dropbox/EclipseWorkspace/Application/Application.jar manifest.txt *
```

...the verbose output contains this:

```
....
adding: FONTS/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: FONTS/.DS_Store(in = 8196) (out= 407)(deflated 95%)
adding: FONTS/domesticmanners.ttf(in = 71116) (out= 44257)(deflated 37%)
....
```

For reference, FONTS is contained within the "Application" folder, the folder from which I'm making the JAR.

So, I assumed I'd be good to go when attempting to run the new JAR file in a folder that doesn't also contain the domesticmanners.ttf file (assumedly with the .ttf file having been bundled into the JAR). However, when I move the JAR to a new empty folder and run it, I'm left with a null pointer exception followed by a large stack trace related to fonts, beginning with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Font$1.getNativeFont(Font.java:68)
```

I'm sure that the only fatal issue with the application is the custom external TTF font for two reasons:

1: I've reexported the project as a JAR without the custom fonts applied and it works like a charm
2: I've dragged the domesticmanners.ttf file into the previously non-functioning JAR's new export folder, whereupon the null pointer is no longer thrown.

I'm still a relatively new CS student and not especially well educated on the functionality of JAR files, but it seems odd to me that the JAR file wouldn't be able to directly reference a file contained within it. Is there problem with my build path, etc.?

(I've read a bunch of other posts about styling font with @font-face/CSS, but I'd really like to be able to use external .tffs).

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getClass().getResourceStream()`. JAR files cannot be accessed using normal `File` functionality.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("FONTS/domesticmanners.ttf");
font=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,is);
Font f = font.deriveFont(40f);
```

Ideally you would also use a `resources` folder.

Comment: Ah ok thanks - after trying that implementation, is there a way to manage this using exclusively JavaFX or to convert an AWT font into a font useable in a JavaFX label? FX has some label functionality like coloring and opacity that I'd like to have that AWT labels seem to lack

Comment: That's a new question that I unfortunately have no idea about. [Please accept my answer if it was correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Going back over your response, I wanted to clarify - I'm not necessarily trying to access the fonts *from* an external JAR - rather, I'm trying to ensure that my JAR export, based on java files that access the .ttf file in the resources folder, won't throw a font-based null pointer exception when run

Comment: Thats why you want to use `getResourceAsStream`